# Adding new element to dynamic array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I know those are basics, but I can't get over with it.
I want to add x times y elements to my array.
When I add 1x100000 elements it's fine.
However, when I try to add 5000x5000 elements, it stops immediately, with many different errors, never bad alloc.
I'd be extremaly gladful if someone can give me a clue about this...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>

class Array
{
    int *tab; //dynamic array
    int cnt; //count
public:
    Array();
    void clearArray();//deleting table
    void test_addValueToArray(int index, int value);
};

Array::Array() : tab(nullptr), cnt(0){;}

void Array::clearArray()
{
    if(cnt==0)
        return;
    delete tab;
    cnt=0;
}

void Array::test_addValueToArray(int index, int value)
{
    int *NewTab = new int[cnt+1];
    for(int i=0;i<index;++i)
        NewTab[i]=tab[i];
    NewTab[index]=value;
    for(int i=index+1;i<cnt+1;++i)
        NewTab[i]=tab[i-1];
    delete[] tab;
    tab=NewTab;
    ++cnt;
}

Array myArray;

int main()
{
    int elements, times;
    std::cout<<"How many elements?";
    std::cin>>elements;
    std::cout<<"How many times?";
    std::cin>>times;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int j=0; j<times; ++j)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<elements ; ++i)
            myArray.test_addValueToArray(0,rand()%1000);
        myArray.clearArray();
    }
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> time=stop-start;
    std::cout<<"Avarage time:"<<time.count()/times<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: First problem: In clearArray you probably wantet `delete[] tab;`, not `delete tab;`.

Second problem: What happens if you access tab[i] after calling clearArray?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because of use of delete[] for lots of continious memory deallocation,
plus you have used only delete tab which should be changed to delete[] tab in cleararray so you can use smart pointers.

plus: In your test_addValueToArray() when cnt=0 you are trying to deallocate memory which is not allocated at all and i didn't understand why you are passing 0 as index while calling addValueToArray() i think it should be i at that point.

So once you fix this and use smart pointers it should work else it will show bad_alloc exception after running for some time.